# How to sort a dictionary with respect of length of values?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a son file. the `key` is a single title , but `Results` do not have fixed length.  For example dic[0:3] is:

```
{'key': 'accounting manager',
 'Results': [{'accountant': 3666.0},
  {'controller': 1254.0},
  {'financial analyst': 553.0},
  {'accounting clerk': 490.0},
  {'office manager': 355.0},
  {'auditor': 309.0},
  {'accounts payable clerk': 284.0},
  {'finance manager': 260.0}]}
{'key': '2d animator',
 'Results': [{'artist': 51.0},
  {'animator': 45.0},
  {'freelancer': 12.0},
]}
{'key': 'employee relations manager',
 'Results': [{'human resources generalist': 142.0},
  {'service manager': 121.0},
  {'human resources specialist': 120.0},
  {'engineering manager': 96.0},
  {'human resources manager': 91.0}]}
```

Can I sort this dic with respect of `len(dic[j]['Results'])` for `j=0,..., len(dic)`? for example the the Len of `Results` of the above instance are 8, 3,5. other ones might be 10, or 100 or,...

The out put of the above:

```
{'key': 'accounting manager',
 'Results': [{'accountant': 3666.0},
  {'controller': 1254.0},
  {'financial analyst': 553.0},
  {'accounting clerk': 490.0},
  {'office manager': 355.0},
  {'auditor': 309.0},
  {'accounts payable clerk': 284.0},
  {'finance manager': 260.0}]}
     {'key': 'employee relations manager',
 'Results': [{'human resources generalist': 142.0},
  {'service manager': 121.0},
  {'human resources specialist': 120.0},
  {'engineering manager': 96.0},
  {'human resources manager': 91.0}]}
{'key': '2d animator',
 'Results': [{'artist': 51.0},
  {'animator': 45.0},
  {'freelancer': 12.0},
]}
```

Comment: Your posted structure is incorrect in that it's not a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this piece of code a while back which will sort a dictionary based on the length of lists which were stored, it should work for python 3.7+ at least

```
dict1 = {'key1': [0,1,3,4,5], 'key2':[1,2], 'key3': [4,5,6]}

dict1_sorted = {k2: dict1[k2] for k2 in sorted(dict1, key=lambda k: len(dict1[k]))}
```

**Edit**

since dic in you example is not a dictionary but a list of dictionaries, you are not trying to 'sort a dictionary with respect of length of values', you are trying to sort a **list** based on the length of a values of the dictionaries it contains, which can be done with the following:

```
dic = [{'key': 'accounting manager',
        'Results': [{'accountant': 3666.0},
                    {'controller': 1254.0},
                    {'financial analyst': 553.0},
                    {'accounting clerk': 490.0},
                    {'office manager': 355.0},
                    {'auditor': 309.0},
                    {'accounts payable clerk': 284.0},
                    {'finance manager': 260.0}]},
       {'key': 'employee relations manager',
        'Results': [{'human resources generalist': 142.0},
                    {'service manager': 121.0},
                    {'human resources specialist': 120.0},
                    {'engineering manager': 96.0},
                    {'human resources manager': 91.0}]},
       {'key': '2d animator',
        'Results': [{'artist': 51.0},
                    {'animator': 45.0},
                    {'freelancer': 12.0}]}
       ]

## assending order
dic_sorted = sorted(dic, key=lambda k: len(k['Results']))
print(dic_sorted)


## decending order 
dic_sorted = sorted(dic, key=lambda k: len(k['Results']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: this is not my question

Comment: 'how sort a dictionary with respect of length of values?' is your question, can you copy more example of dic[i] so I can test

Comment: dic is a list, not a dictionary

Comment: @elham--you did not post a list of dictionaries (i.e. missing outer [] and a comma between dictionaries).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your input is a list of dictionaries, sorting each element in reverse by the length of the value of the 'Results' key can be done with this expression:

```
sorted(dic, key=lambda k: len(k['Results']),reverse=True)
```